# Function for list and unpacked list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two possible ways of calling a function.

With a list:

```
some_list = [1,2,3,4]
my_function(some_list)
```

And with a unpacked list or just multiple arguments:

```
my_function(*some_list) == my_function(1,2,3,4)
```

which is equal to the first case as well:

```
my_function(some_list) == my_function(*some_list) == my_function(1,2,3,4)
```

In the function `my_function` i want to iterate over the list. So for the frist case the function looks like this:

```
def my_function(arg):
    for i in arg:
         # do something
```

Now for the second case i will repack the unpacked list, resulting into the following function:

```
def my_function(*arg):
    for i in arg:
        # do something
```

---

Is there a way how to have a nice single function for both cases?

Comment: check this article [https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/]. this might be useful

Comment: How do you want it to handle multiple list inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an autounpacking checker decorator for wrapp the function:

```
import functools


def autounpack(f):
  @functools.wraps(f)
  def wrapped(*args):
    if len(args) == 1 and type(args[0]) == list:
      return f(*args[0])
    else:
      return f(*args)
  return wrapped


@autounpack
def my_f(*args):
  print(args)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/MX33/1)